# How to populate a p:selectOneMenu with value from database

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces

I would like to load a `<p:selectOneMenu>` with a database value.

Ex: Imagine that you have two entities. Person and Car. A car only have one person. When you are adding a new car you should select one person. My selectonemeu is loaded with a list of person and I select one. When I need to edit this car entity, i would like to load my selectonemenu with this value (selected) and other values from database.

```
<p:selectOneMenu id="time" value="#{personBean.person.car}"
   converter="entityConverter" required="true" > 
<f:selectItem itemLabel="Select a value..." noSelectionOption="true" /> 
<f:selectItems value="#{carBean.listCar}" var="g"
itemLabel="#{g.name}" itemValue="#{g}" /> 
</p:selectOneMenu>
```

My "#{carBean.listCar}" is a method that connect in my database and put values on page. I loaded it values to "#{personBean.person.car}" in order to add it. What I´m trying to do is in edit mode, load the selected value to appear in screen.

Comment: Make sure that your `playerBean.player.time` value is filled when loading the page in edit mode and that its value can be compared with the values in your `<f:selectItems>` list.

Comment: Are u getting values from database to your selectItems?

Comment: What exactly is the problem you're having with this code? (apart from the code itself not really being self-documenting .. e.g. a "person" is not a "time" and "g" is totally unclear)

Comment: I updated my description with more information.